# Ejecutar powershell desde SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, powershell

estoy intentando obtener una consulta de PowerShell, donde me devuelva el espacio libre en todos los discos de mis servidores vinculados, ésto mediante una consulta distribuida, sin embargo al momento de ejecutar dicha consulta con el xp_cmdshell obtendo un error, dejaré la consulta que estoy intentando realizar y el error que me devuelve. Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
declare @cmd varchar(200)
set @cmd = 'xp_cmdshell ''powershell $discos = Get-WmiObject -Class 
win32_logicaldisk -Filter "VolumeName = ''Respaldos''"'''
print @cmd

exec (@cmd).
```

Y el error devuielto es el siguiente:

```
Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 1
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'Respaldos'.
```

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Ya solucioné el primer error, sin embargo ahora me muestra otro: Get-WmiObject : No se encuentra ningún parámetro de posición que acepte el argumento 'Respaldos'.

Comment: Checa este link a ver si te sirve, no lo hago desde SQL Server, pero igual funciona.
http://dbamex.blogspot.com/2017/10/revision-de-espacio-en-servidores.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucho buscar, encontre la respuesta aquí:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2444/script-to-get-available-and-free-disk-space-for-sql-server/

Dejo ésto por si alguien le sirve.

Saludos

Comment: Que bueno que haya encontrado la solución, pero por favor, [edit] la respuesta para agregar la información relevante del enlace. Lea: [cómo escribir una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.